# Tableau SubTotal Formatting

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to ask if someone know how to work around with Sub Total colors.

Currently I want highlight the sub total header only but when I apply the header it also applied to my color header.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First remove the color formatting that is already applied.

Then go to `Format`, click on `Shading(Paint Bucket Icon)`, then under section `Total` set the color for `Pane` and `Header`.

Comment: Hello @akshay, yup that is what I did but it also add shade on the Country Names. which should not be shaded.